# Kusto show function | show info about function

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Is there a keyword to show a function in Kusto? For example if I have a function like this:

```
let EnterString = (a:string) { strcat("You entered '", a, "'.") };
```

Can I call something like .show to show the function?

```
.show EnterString
```

Expected output:

```
let EnterString = (a:string) { strcat("You entered '", a, "'.") };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use:

```
.show function EnterString
```

> [.show function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-function)
>
> Parameters
>
> The parameters required by the function.
>
> Body
>
> (Zero or more) let statements followed by a valid CSL expression that is evaluated upon function invocation.